# Boundary of product cartesian

Tags: products, manifolds-with-boundary

What's the boundary of $\Omega\times (a,b)$, where $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: What do you think it is or what have you tried to find what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The boundary of a cylinder is composed by the two bases and by the lateral face. In your case:
$$
\partial (\Omega \times (a,b)) = (\partial \Omega \times (a,b)) \cup (\Omega \times \partial (a,b))
$$